# how can set play button image png in videoview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

how can set play button image png in videoview?

I tried more methods, but still cannot alpha compositing

now in my code, I use the previewImage to load video image, but it's no play button.

I hope I can add alpha compositing play button, but how can I do?

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rvideo"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="280dp">

                <VideoView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/video"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="280dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/previewImageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="center"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

```
holder.rvideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            glide.load(newFeedModels.get(position).getFeedMediaVideo()).into(holder.previewImageView);
            try{
             mediaController = new MediaController(context);
             mediaController.setAnchorView(holder.video);
             Uri vvideo = Uri.parse(newFeedModels.get(position).getFeedMediaVideo());
             holder.video.setMediaController(mediaController);
             holder.video.setVideoURI(vvideo);
             holder.previewImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     holder.previewImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     holder.video.start();
                 }
             });
             holder.video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                     holder.previewImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 }
             });
            } catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Error Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnHD"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:src="YOURIMGSOURCE" />
```